# Trouble updating a particular user in a mysql database

Tags: mysql

im trying to update a particular user that is logged in using UPDATE mysql command, but instead it is going to the first user that is in the database itself, if you can help id appreciate it

Edit: Im wanting to increment the number of 'items' that a user has, but for the code below its only going to the first user in the database

```
<?php
session_start();
        $dbhost = 'localhost';
        $dbuser = '';
        $dbpass = '';
        $dbname = '';
        $conn = mysql_connect($dbhost,$dbuser,$dbpass)
            or die ('Error connecting to mysql');
        mysql_select_db($dbname);
            $query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET item = item + 1 ",
        mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item']));
            mysql_query($query);
        ?>
```

Comment: You don't have a where clause?

Comment: $_POST['item'] is your where clausule ?

Comment: What is `$_POST['item']` identifying? What database column does it correlate to?

Comment: i dont know what its modifying but if i remove anything then it doesnt work

Answer (score 1):

Your `sprintf()` call has a parameter, but no placeholder:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET item = item + 1 ",
      mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item']));
```

Probably this is supposed to be something like the following, assuming an `INT` column named `item`

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET item = item + 1 WHERE item = %d ",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['item']));
```

### **UPDATE**

If you are trying to target a specific user only, then you need that user's id or username in `$_POST` instead of `item`.  You'll need to post the output of `var_dump($_POST)` for us to see just what values you've received in post.

Assuming a string `username`, use:

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET item = item + 1 WHERE username = '%s' ",
    mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['username']));
```

Comment: yes, the item has INT. what exactly does the %d mean? and wouldnt i need WHERE item.id?

Comment: If `item.id` is your column (`id` in table `item`), then yes use `item.id`.  `%d` means an integer value placeholder passed to `sprintf()`.  It maps to `$_POST['item']`

Comment: ok, i updated it where it says WHERE item=%d since the column is 'item' and now its not even entering it into the database

Comment: Please edit your question to describe exactly what you intend to do.  For example, it looks like you're trying to increment the `item` column of the `users` table for rows where `item == $_POST['item']`

Answer (score 0):

you need some kind of where clause.  specify which user you want to actually update with extra conditions.

Comment: ok, but how would i do that? like in the database, the users are under the column 'username'

Answer (score 0):

YOu need to know which user you want to update...

```
$query = sprintf("UPDATE users SET item = item + 1 WHERE userId="+ $userId,
```

or something like that...